# Unknown build errors when building for Android

Tags: unity

I'm experiencing the following errors when I try to Build + Run to Android and have no idea what to do about them. Can anyone help?

[image: Unity errors]

- Observed package id 'tools' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools.new' (Expected 'C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools')
  UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
- Already observed package id 'tools' in 'C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools.new'
  UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
- Transform component could not be found on game object. Adding one!
  UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
- GameObject has multiple Transform components! Merged into single one.
  UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
- CheckConsistency: GameObject does not reference component MonoBehaviour. Fixing.
  UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
- Transform component deleted: GameObject pointer is invalid
  UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
- Error building Player: 3 errors
- Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
  UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
- UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0021f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:187 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:94 
  UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()